What happened with the 31.5 ft giant in Jubbulpore district (now Jabalpur), India, August 8, 1934?
Giant Human Skeleton — Legs 10 Feet Long
While perusing a list of tall people on Wikipedia, I came upon this claim:

A skeleton 31.5 ft (9.6 m) long, found in the river bank in the Jubbulpore district on August 8, 1934. Initially believed to be a giant human, it was identified as a giant non-human ape soon after unearthing.

I immediately questioned the "fact" that it was identified as a 31.5 ft ape, because I think archaeologists and related scientists would have known better by 1934.
Sources
Wikipedia points to two sources to back this claim up, the first one from The Daily News (Perth, WA, Thu 9 Aug 1934):

A DISCOVERY of world-wide importance is reported from the village of Paintiha, in the Jubbulpore district (Central Provinces), where a giant human skeleton has been unearthed.
A man washing in the river noticed the skeleton protruding from a bank, and had to get the assistance of three others before he could pull it out.
The skeleton proved to be 31½ feet long. The legs are 10ft. long.
The skeleton has been removed to the palace of the chief of Daiyha State.

The second source, mentioning the "ape" angle only four days later, Manawatu Times, Volume 59, Issue 192, 13 August 1934:

The skeleton is now believed to be that of a Prehistoric giant ape. The skeleton has been placed in the palace at Ramgrah, pending an examination by Geologists, who regard it as enormously interesting.

Questions
I have not been able to find whatever happened to this find. Two questions comes to mind:

Are there any more information about this find? Maybe a paper by an actual archaeologist or a geologist as they refer to in the paper, or perhaps an exhibition — assuming it actually existed, it must have been a remarkable skeleton, and by 1934 there must have been photographs and news articles in British papers.
Would the science not have been sufficiently advanced by then for an archaeologist or related scientist to exclude the possibility of this being a giant ape?


I can't find any village called "Paintiha", however, that doesn't tell us much as names change, especially with British transcriptions of names in India. Google maps has it as being about 700 km/430 mi (by road minus a bit to make straight line) between Jabalpur and Ramgarh, which is a hell of a long way to take a fossil, but maybe it was closer to Ramgarh? All together I suspect fake...

@bob1 I doubt it is fake as such, but of course it was neither human nor ape. I could also not make sense of the village/city names but I have zero experience in Indian names so i didn't have much to go on.

I did a quick search, and turns out Worldbuilding.SE has already had a question about the theoretical max size for a bipedal creature. I don't think they came to a definitive answer, but most of the issues I raised in my answer were discussed in a bit more depth.

@pipe By "fake", I was meaning the reports of such things, perhaps false would have been a better word. The fact that you can only find it in Australian and NZ newspapers indicates that either these are the only ones digitized or there was something incorrect about the report and other newspapers didn't cover it.

I can't find anything but old news reports about the "reports". This seems a pretty clear indication that nobody actually preserved any bones with this reported length to study further. If they weren't preserved for examination, there's no reason to expect anything new could possibly be found or forthcoming. By now even the people who claim to have found it are likely dead. A 10 year old from then would now be 100.
Also this seems ... rather unlikely. The largest verified human being was a bit under 9ft, and the largest Ape species ever found by archeology was about 12 ft. Its not ridiculous that there might be slightly larger out there undiscovered, but 2.5x larger* would be kind of ridiculous. We currently just have no real evidence that the basic Ape skeletal design can (or ever did) get anywhere near that large. So its probably best at this point to assume some kind of hoax, misprint, or mistranslation. If its not, we'll eventually find something concrete indicating that, so no harm no foul.
Note that every entry in the list of unverified claims that was linked to in the question which claimed larger than 15ft and actually had the bones saved, ended up actually being some extinct animal in the Proboscidea Order of mammals (the order that includes Elephants, Mammoths, and Mastodons). So if this were a betting matter, the smart money would go here.
Following are pictures of Robert Wadlow, the tallest recorded human, and of Gigantopithecus scaled next to a slightly under 6' man.


For fun, note that the original 1933 movie Kaiju King Kong, when he was scaling the Empire State Building, was only 24 feet tall!


* - Realize that weight would vary by roughly a cube of the height, while bone strength would only square (volume vs cross-section). I checked and a 30 foot long Orca weighs about 22,000 lbs. Of course it doesn't have to support all that weight on land, while a 22,000 lb person would have to support all that weight on two femurs. T-Rex's were about 40 feet tall (and about the same weight as an Orca), so its theoretically possible for a bipedal creature, but Tyrannosaur bones aren't exactly impossible to find either.

T-rexes were about 40 feet long and about 15 or 20 feet high.  they weren't 20 feet  tall.

@MAGolding - Every picture I've seen had their posture almost horizontal with their legs under the middle, but its a fair point that a lot of that length was just tail (which of course Apes don't possess).

Perusal of Google Books indicates that a number of dinosaur skeletons were found in Jubbulpore district. One example: Records of the Geological Survey of India, Vol. 51, 1921, p. 9 "Dr. Matley has also discovered in the Lameta beds of Jubbulpore a large number of hitherto unknown remains of dinosaurs. They include the right and left scapulæ (66 inches long), the right humerus (53 inches long),  ... and other parts of ... Titanosaurus indicus Lydekker."

Picture deserves names

Even though this is a "probably no" answer it's impossible to prove a negative so this is probably as good as we can get. And I would like it on the record that I did not believe it was an ape! :) It's the whole square-cube law that made me think that any scientist would quickly disregard claims of human/ape.

I think its probably fair to use The Sagan Standard here. "I found bones for a Kaiju" certainly qualifies as an extraordinary claim.
